# SystemD Conversion - In Progress

Tags: systemd, nvidia, gentoo

I've successfully converted my 4 year old installation of KDE4/SysV/Grub Legacy to KDE5 - Plasma/SystemD/Grub2.  I have some questions for anyone who has done something similarly:

### Information

```
$ sudo lspci  
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Host Bridge (rev a1)  
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)  
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)  
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)  
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3)  
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3)  
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1)  
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)  
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2)  
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)  
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)  
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)  
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)    
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration  
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map  
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller  
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control  
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control  
01:07.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR922X Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)  
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti] (rev a1)  
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

$ sudo uname -a
Linux host-removed 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 01:05:09 CDT 2016 x86_64 AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 255 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

If you need more information, let me know in the comments, and I'll add it to the block above.

---

### Issues

1. I know I have a lot of Cruft.  Can I remove the directory `/etc/init.d` now that the major switchover is complete?
2. Does anyone know the `XSESSION` value for Plasma?  I'd like to remove SDDM (`systemctl stop sddm && systemctl disable sddm`), and use `startx`, so that I can research #3 without my laptop.
3. Using the [Gentoo nouveau Wiki Entry](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau), I did successfully remove `x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers` and compiled in `nouveau` and DRI with KMS, but upon reboot, all I get is a black screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left corner.  Note that the terminal works, and modesetting was successful, until the SDDM service starts. In the interim, I've switched back to `x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers`.
4. `snd-hda-intel` and `snd-hda-intel-generic` start but spit out something about error -16 or error -116.  I'd print the exact error here, but switching terminals causes a lockup, which is why I'm attempting #3.

Comment: It's "systemd", not "SystemD". Don't use nouveau!

Comment: Why should I not use nouveau?

Comment: It's buggy, it can't play "real" games (Steam won't run for instance), it's far behind nVidia drivers, and if you use a Chromium-base browser you won't get much acceleration. It's mostly good for really old video cards, yours is not that old.

Comment: So how would you suggest I troubleshoot the graphics switching.  I'd like to be able to use Ctrl + Alt + F(n) for a TTY, but doing so causes a black screen with a blinking cursor when switching back to X.  There is no starts value for Plasma, as systemd expects to use sddm as an enabled target.